# JQuery Datepicker/Datetimepicker - How to set MaxDate in java according to a selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm not so good in Javascript - but I'm trying this:

I had a list of events, where the user can "program to close" the event in a future date.

but, this future date cannot be after the event.

Then, I need to set a maxdate for each event.

I am using JQuery DatePicker - and to set the maxdate I do this:

```
    $('#closeevent').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: new Date(2016, 8, 15, 8, 0)
});
```

maxDate = 2016/8/15 08:00

My problem:

How I can change the "2016, 8, 15, 8, 0" (maxDate value) onClick a button for each event (because each event has a different maxDate.

event 1 ... maxDate (2016, 9, 10, 8, 0)  .... [button onClick:..]
event 2 ... maxDate (2016, 10, 22, 10, 30)  .... [button onClick:..]

If I click Button for event1 - the maxDate change to 2016, 9, 10, 8, 0..

If I click button for event2  - the maxDate change to 2016, 10, 22, 10, 30..

tks a lot

Comment: You aren't using jQuery datepicker, or your code would say `datepicker` instead of `datetimepicker`.

Comment: @BobRodes tks a lot for your observation! I correct the title of the question. You are right, but datepicker and datetimepicker have a similar core and the solution for the question Works fine in booth.

Comment: Good to know that, but it certainly wasn't a given!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the beforeShowDay property to assign a function that is called before each date is displayed.  The return allows you to control days with a much higher granularity.

You can look at this fiddle for an example. 
https://jsfiddle.net/tv760t1s/

```
var maxDate = new Date(2016, 8, 15, 8, 0);
$(".dateChange").click(function() {
  maxDate = new Date($(this).attr('value'));
  console.log(maxDate);
});
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: new Date(2016, 8, 15, 8, 0),
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    console.log(date, maxDate);
    if (date > maxDate) {
      return [false, 'noShowClass', 'Date time not available'];
    } else {
      return [true, '', ''];
    }
  }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div>    
  <input type='text' id='datepicker' value=''>
  <input class='dateChange' type='button' value='2016-08-15 08:00:00'>
  <input class='dateChange' type='button' value='2016-09-10 08:00:00'>
</div>
```

Comment: tks a lot for your time and help! Great solution!! Works fine! I only got 2 problems - 1- The origintal MAXDATE must be the "MAX OF ALL" - In our example the original maxdate is 2016-08-15 - If I try change to 2016-12-31.. they don't change. They stop on 2016/08/15. I solve this identifying the last date and put this as the original Maxdate. No problem... The second issue is with the TIME - but I think this is a problem with the datepicker - the maxdate only counts the date, not the time.. I can select 2016-08-15 23:59:59..